# JqueryUi splitButton not showing in the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Hi guys I'm a jquery noobie, just started jqueryUI

**Problem OverView:**
I'm trying to use jqueryUI tabs inside which there is a JqueryUI Split Button (which is not being rendered). Cheddar ,Mushrooms and Bocon are suppose to be rendered as split buttons.
I have copied markup and jquery from the sites so I wouldn't make any mistake but still it doesn't work.
*Firefox snapshot*
[image]

**Code:**
I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OwaisQureshi/MnGzM/) for you guys , but it is not working as it was in my browser.
*Jquery*

```
    <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css"
    rel="Stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.21.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs(); //Vstudio intellisense shows .tabs() and .buttonset()
        $('#Toppings').buttonset(); //this means JqueryUi is attached.
    }
    );
```

*HTML*

```
<div id="MainBox">
    <!--MainBox-->
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Step 1: Your Background</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Step 2: Your Finances</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Step 3: Your Results</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <div class="subBox">
                <div class="smallBox">
                    fgggghgh</div>
                <div class="smallBox">
                    fgggghgh</div>
                <div class="smallBox">
                    fgggghgh</div>
                <div class="smallBox">
                    fgggghgh</div>
            </div>
            <div class="subBox">
            </div>
            <div class="subBox">
            </div>
            <div class="subBox">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <div id="Toppings">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />
                <label for="check1">
                    Cheddar
                </label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" />
                <label for="check2">
                    Mushrooms
                </label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" />
                <label for="check3">
                    Bacon
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
            <p>
                Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate,
                pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat,Really dummy text.</p>
            <p>
                Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam
                ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque.Really dummy text twoS.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will work, if you change your labels to point to the correct input elements. The for="" attribute has to equal the id of the input.

example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />
<label for="checkbox1">Cheddar</label>
```